# how to check if list is filtered or not with boolean

Tags: android, list, filter, filtering, adapter

I've implemented searchView filter on my recycler view. Now I need to find when my list is filtered and when it is not.

This is my Filterable implementation in my custom adapter:

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            dataList = (List<ProductLight>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            List<ProductLight> FilteredArrayNames = new ArrayList<ProductLight>();
            constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            for (int i = 0; i < dataListFilter.size(); i++) {
                ProductLight dataNames = dataListFilter.get(i);
                if (dataNames.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString())){
                    FilteredArrayNames.add(dataNames);
                }
            }
            results.count = FilteredArrayNames.size();
            results.values = FilteredArrayNames;
            return results;
        }
    };
    return filter;
}
```

And in my Fragment(which has searchview in optionMenu) I'm filtering my list like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search_menu);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            isListFiltered = true ;
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Now I don't know where should I switch `isListFiltered` to false.

Comment: when query = ""

Comment: or when searchView.isIconified()